# Count number of group by rows in hibernate with criteria

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, group-by

I want to count the number of `group by` rows with hibernate Criteria API, but i can only count number of rows aggregated in each group:

```
ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.groupProperty("color"))
        .add(Projections.rowCount());
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria("ProductEntity");
criteria.setProjection(projectionList);
// adding some criteria
List results = criteria.list();
```

Above code will results in this query:

```
select p.color, count(*) from product p group by p.color
```

But i want this query:

```
select count(*) from (select p.color from product p group by p.color)
```

I know it's possible with HQL, but i don't want to use it. So how can i do this with Criteria API?

Comment: Pusker's answer only works for group by queries with one column. I wrote an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65030998/2114737

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know how many different colors are present you should use

```
Projections.countDistinct("color")
```

This will result a query which will return the same result as this:

```
select count(*) from (select p.color from product p group by p.color)
```